# Adding photos to gallery in Google Play Newsstand

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-newsstand

I'm trying to add several pictures in a gallery of my articles in Google Play Newsstand with no success. I tried adding 3 pictures with the right size, but they can't be displayed into the article's gallery.

```xml
<media:content url="[URL IMAGE]"
        type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190">
  <media:description type="plain">[DESCRIPTION]</media:description>
  <media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">[AUTHOR]</media:credit>
</media:content>
```

This is an example of my `<item>` element:

```xml
<item>
    <title><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[http://google/wE-bacdkE]]></link>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[Today we’re introducing a new age-based rating system for apps and games on Google Play. We know that people in different countries have different ideas about what content is appropriate for kids, teens and adults, so today’s announcement will help developers better label their apps for the right audience. Consistent with industry best practices, this change will give developers an easy way to communicate familiar and locally relevant content ratings to their users and help improve app discovery and engagement by letting people choose content that is right for them.

    Starting now, developers can complete a content rating questionnaire for each of their apps and games to receive objective content ratings. Google Play’s new rating system includes official ratings from the International Age Rating Coalition (IARC) and its participating bodies, including the Entertainment Software Rating Board (ESRB), Pan-European Game Information (PEGI), Australian Classification Board, Unterhaltungssoftware Selbstkontrolle (USK) and Classificação Indicativa (ClassInd). Territories not covered by a specific ratings authority will display an age-based, generic rating. The process is quick, automated and free to developers. In the coming weeks, consumers worldwide will begin to see these new ratings in their local markets.]]></content:encoded>
    <author>Grupo Jorgesys</author>
    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/images/1973850.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>
    <media:content url="http://flv.grupoJorgesys.com/flash/elnorte/articulo/mp3/online/1/489/488838.mp3" medium="audio"><media:title><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></media:title><media:description><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/images/1973852.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android0]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/images/1973856.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android1]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/images/1973858.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android2]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/images/1973860.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

</item>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the size of my images defined into the `.rss` file was `width="538"` and `height="190"` a size that cant be displayed in the gallery of the article. I have changed the size of the images to `width="800"` and `height="400"` and now the images are being displayed.

The characteristics for the images in a Google Newsstand Edition are:

**Images for display inside article body and gallery**: Users want to see beautiful, large images. The shortest side of an image should be **800px**, but ideally larger for better display on tablets.

**Cover image** requirements:

- 300 DPI image resolution
- JPEG compression set to high
- width of 2400 pixels (height may vary depending on the aspect ratio of your magazine)

**Preview image** requirements:

- 300 DPI image resolution
- JPEG compression set to high
- 2400 pixels wide (height can vary depending on aspect ratio of magazine)

More info:

- **[Google Play Newsstand News Inclusion Guidelines.](https://support.google.com/producer/answer/4304250?hl=en)**
- **[Cover and Preview images](https://support.google.com/producer/answer/2924226?hl=en)**

Now the images are displayed without problem:

[image]

Comment: Maybe Chuck really wanted your bounty ¯\_| ಠ ∧ ಠ |_/¯

Comment: Ha, no worries.  Sometimes it's the silly things and worth checking them first.  Glad she figured it out.